# Know that Patent expired or not

Tags: expiration, us5934963a, specific-patent

I had designed a similar invention like the Patent [`US5,934,963`](http://www.google.com/patents/US5934963) but have found this patent was already in force.

It seems to have lapsed and been re-instated several times...

Can you determine the current status?

Answer (score 0):

No, the patent has not expired. It was filed for in 1998 so it will probably be active through most of 2018.

Google Patents [shows](https://www.google.com/patents/US5934963?dq=5,934,963&hl=en&sa=X&ei=FQ8rVKnWDabRiwKqq4CwBA&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAA) that it expired September 27, 2011 due to failure to pay a maintenance fee, but that a petition for late payment was granted.

Your best bet is likely to look into differentiating your invention, or licensing that patent.

Comment: @user11607 Glad to help. Please mark this answer as accepted by clicking the checkmark if it helped you.